# parse php sdk and error code 251 Twitter credential verification failed

Tags: php, twitter, parse-platform

I use parse-php-sdk.Now I need my customers login with twitter then add them as parse users.Because there is no function I can use as twitter logining in ParseUser.php, so I write one:

```
public static function logInWithTwitter($id, $access_token, $expiration_date = null)
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new ParseException("Cannot log in twitter user without an id.");
    }
    if (!$access_token) {
        throw new ParseException(
            "Cannot log in twitter user without an access token."
        );
    }
    if (!$expiration_date) {
        $expiration_date = new \DateTime();
        $expiration_date->setTimestamp(time() + 86400 * 60);
    }
    $data = json_encode(['authData' =>
        ["twitter" => [
            "id" => $id, "access_token" => $access_token,
            "expiration_date" => ParseClient::getProperDateFormat($expiration_date)
        ]]
    ]);
    $result = ParseClient::_request("POST", "/1/users", "", $data);
    $user = new ParseUser();
    $user->_mergeAfterFetch($result);
    $user->handleSaveResult(true);
    ParseClient::getStorage()->set("user", $user);
    return $user;
}
```

But when I finished login with twitter,

```
error occurs: Code : 251 Message:Twitter credential verification failed.
```

. I try to look for solutions, but all I found are things about apps platform problems, and they can fix if by setting consumerKey and consumerSecret in TWSignedRequest. But I don't know whether I need to set twitter consumerKey and consumerSecret, if I need to do this ,where should I set?

Comment: I have add consumerKey to parse settings just now, but the error occurs in the same way